# Что такое "сложность"? Нужна ли вообще эта метка?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки

Сегодня один незарегистрированный пользователь (не хочу говорить ничего плохого, но про таких, вы и сами много чего сказать можете), задал вопрос "Хочу набрать 10 отрицательных голосов" и все такое...
Вопрос был отмечен меткой [сложность](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c). Задавшись вопросом, что это такое и с чем его едят, я проанализировал информацию по этой метке и понял, что она вообще не о чем. Пользовались данной метой аж 31 раз (включая этот с которого я начал).
Нужна ли эта метка? Что полезного она привносит в сообщество? У меня нет на эти вопросы позитивных ответов.

**Предлагаю ее удалить:**

- данная метка не несет никакой смысловой нагрузки;
- используется редко (аж 31 раз);
- является меткой, подобной метке [ошибка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0) (от которой сообщество недавно избавилось), в нее можно добавить что угодно, так как пользователи обращаются на сайт с теми или иными по сложности вопросами.

**UPDATE:**

Сегодня добавил описание метки [сложность](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c) как вычислительная сложность.

Comment: Речь о [вычислительной сложности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C). Метка скорее нужна, чем нет. Разумеется, ей нужно адекватное описание.

Comment: @Nofate Тогда получается, что далеко не все пользователи понимают ее предназначение. Как по мне, тогда так и надо написать `вычислительная-сложность`, длинновато, зато всем понятно.

Comment: Ок, тогда вопрос снимаю с повестки дня.

Comment: @Nofate, ответы - в ответы.

Comment: @Qwertiy это не ответ, это мнение.

Comment: @Qwertiy сложность формально еще и про P/NP, SAT и прочее, а не только про асимптотику.

Comment: @Nofate, по-прежнему ответы - в ответы ;) И нет, это именно ответ.

Comment: 31 не так уж и мало, тем более сайт растёт.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин уже 30 )))

Comment: Я думаю что метка нужна, она сразу же характеризует смысл вопроса, но не против переименования в `алгоритмическая-сложность` это более чёткая формулировка.

Comment: Хорошо, что [tag:сложность],хоть какое-то разнообразие. Обычно такие вопрошающие почему-то ставят [tag:php].

Comment: @Arhad Ну почему, они иногда ставят Java... ))) Ну php просто короче..., тут выбор очевиден )))

Comment: @Nofate обратите пожалуйста внимание на [еще один вопрос по поводу синонимизации меток, там уже более 10 человек проголосовало.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7041/%d0%9c%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-software-%d0%b8-%d0%9f%d0%9e-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%86-%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81) Там действительно не нужные метки. Спасибо.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

У нас есть две метки - [сложность](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c) и [асимптотика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0).
Мне кажется, что это одно и то же и надо их синонимизировать.

За направление голосуем в комментариях.

Comment: Сделать основной [tag:сложность].

Comment: Сделать основной [tag:асимптотика].

Comment: Сделать основной [tag:асимптотическая-сложность].

Comment: Асимптотика это более частное, не любая сложность асимптотическая, хотя наиболее часто говорят именно про асимптотику. Так что если объединять, то под сложностью, если это вообще надо.