# Метки [software] и [ПО], закрыть с ними наконец-то вопрос

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Это какой-то дурдом с этими метками (объединяем/удаляем и т. д.), иногда эти темы уже и не хочется поднимать, но к сожалению пока-что, у нас на ресурсе эти проблемы не извелись. Это круговорот информации, тут уж ничего не поделаешь.
Хочу поднять вопрос который как-то поднимали, а именно вопрос: ["долой метку [software] и подобные безликие метки"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4338/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83-software-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8), только в ином ключе.

В предыдущем случае обсуждался вопрос об удалении меток [software](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/software), [по](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be), [программы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b). С меткой [программы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b) вопрос закрыт, а вот с остальными как-то заглох процесс. Если эти метки действительно нужны и действительно несут какую-то важную смысловую нагрузку, то есть смысл их оставить и само-собой объединить, так-как они являются тем же самым только на разных языках.
На данный момент у метки [по](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be) - 13 вопросов, а у [software](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/software)  - 20.
Также хочу напомнить, что более года назад поднимался вопрос, что [меткам нужно время](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4343/%d0%9c%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f).
Я не специалист в области времени, но у меня также вопрос, сколько времени надо выждать, чтоб понять, нужна ли метка?

Comment: Что тут обсуждать, естественно они не нужны. Просто бессмысленные метки с <20 вопросов плодятся быстрее, чем мы в состоянии от них избавляться, поэтому они всегда будут. Какой-то реальной проблемы в этом нет.

Comment: Вот уверен на 100% процентов, если удалите их (особенно достигнув 2к репутации, чтобы редактировать без проверяющих) — никто вам слова плохого не скажет. Очень вряд ли кто-то тут будет, кто будет против их удаления и сможет привести хоть один внятный довод почему.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Проблема не в том, что я или кто-то другой их удалит, а быстрее, что их будут создавать опять и опять. Я за удаление данных меток и еще есть парочка на примете. По поводу репутации, я на ресурсе не гоняюсь за ней, у меня иные цели. Быстрее это поиск и анализ. Редко задаю вопросы, точнее задаю больше на Мета ru SO, а на ru SO больше отвечаю, и то редко.

Comment: @VladSpirin Ну учитывая практику здесь, скажу что подобные вопросы почти в 100% случаях висели в воздухе, пока я сам не брал и не разгребал это лично. Поэтому тут (к сожаленью) очень вряд ли будут большие кол-ва желающих это сделать. Кстати, очень не факт, что кто-то будет воскрешать метки. Попробуйте всё удалить, и если вопросы по этим меткам возникнут в ощутимых количествах (когда дольше удалять, чем писать вопрос на мете), то вернёмся к этому обсуждению снова.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Благодарю за совет. Постараюсь не мозолить вам глаза и делать больше полезных действий для ресурса, чем делал до сих пор. Если чем обидел или зацепил, извиняюсь. У меня нет такой практики, кого-то обижать ) Хорошего вам вечера и отличных выходных.

Comment: @VladSpirin Да вы никого не беспоите и не обижаете, и делать что-то полезное или нет — дело добровольное. Это я всё не в упрёк говорил. Просто сообщество здесь в некоторых вещах не сильно проявляет инициативу (к сожаленью). К примеру, в удалении меток. Вот моему же предложению больше года и результаты не впечатляют, как видите сами.

Comment: Удалить, удалить... А альтернатива какая? За объединение 1 голос только. Куда вопросы то перенесутся и что мне ставить, если я вдруг захочу/начну писать софт, а не гребанные сайтики? (Да, знаю, опоздал я, но все же)

Comment: @DaemonHK Не очень понятно, серьезно вы пишите или это ирония. Я в своем ответе написал, на какие именно метки я их заменял. На вопросы по написанию софта метки ставятся абсолютно так же, как и по "гребаным сайтикам" - используемого языка программирования, ОС, библиотек, технологий и т.п.

Comment: @DaemonHK У нас тут демократия, голосуйте за объединение, проблема то в чем? Эмоции тут излишни. Предложите альтернативу. Критиканов у нас много, что-то стоящее предлагает не так много людей.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight ааа, понял кажется, вы удалили эти метки как тег-спам

Comment: @VladSpirin никаких эмоций, просто пытался разобраться, а то вижу что метки не нужны и как быть дальше не совсем понятно

Comment: @DaemonHK значит ирония ))) Метки же не проблема, всегда если уж так надо будет отметить какую-то технологию можно создать новую и описать ее.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Голосуем:

#### Удалить данные метки навсегда

Answer (score 3):

Поскольку 11/1 и никаких аргументов против, я просто прошелся по вопросам и заменил данные метки на более подходящие: метки конкретного ПО для вопросов по работе с этим ПО, метку [поиск-программ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc) для вопросов по поиску программ; либо совсем удалил для вопросов, где они были явно избыточны.

Метки [по](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be) и [software](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/software) уничтожены. Туда же отправился [soft](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/soft), в котором было 4 вопроса, надеюсь никто не против. Если вы видите, что бессмысленные метки создают заново, предложите правки с их удалением или создайте предложение на добавление в черный список, если ситуация выходит из под контроля.

Answer (score -1):

Голосуем:

#### Объединить и оставить, добавить подробное описание