# Метки [приложения] и [приложение]: синонимизировать или удалить?

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток, удаление-метки

На просторах ruSO существуют две следующие метки: [приложение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) и [приложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f). В связи с тем, что я их обнаружил, у меня возник следующий вопрос:

**Зачем** они вообще существуют? Насколько я вижу, вопросы в этих метках схожи лишь тем, что в них в принципе можно вписать слово "приложение" (в единственном или множественном числе). В них всевозможные вопросы по всевозможным программам, прилагам, мобильным приложениям и т. п. В то же время, существует более или менее понятная метка [мобильные-приложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f). Приложение, по сути, и является мобильным приложением (если оно не на Android, то это уже *программа*). Поэтому предлагаю их:

- Либо сжечь (лучше всего), так как большая часть вопросов в них к приложениям не имеет никакого реального отношения,
- Либо синонимизировать отдельно от [мобильные-приложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f),
- Либо (на мой взгляд, хуже всего), синонимизировать вместе с [мобильные-приложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f).

Comment: Сжечь, как неинформативную.

Comment: "*если оно не на Android, то это уже программа*" - нет, в windows тоже называюттся приложениями. Но метки всё равно надо удалить, см ответ.

Comment: @Зонтик, на 97% приложение все-таки относится к Android. Если сомневаетесь — забейте в интернете "приложение" и "приложение -Android". И сравните цифры количеств полученных результатов.

Comment: @Зонтик, это ж не гугл, это ruSO! Там метки кто угодно какие угодно ставит. Есть даже задачи по питону без метки питон, что уж говорить про андроид! Вы в гугле проверьте.

Comment: @Глеб вы смысл вопросов посмотрите.  В большинстве вопросов метка [tag:android] прикреплена. С меткой [tag:приложения] реально больше вопросов, которые никак с андроидом не связаны. Примеры: 1) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1494322/ 2) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1485189/ 3) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1172018/ 4) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1110606/ 5) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1161433/ - и таких штук 50. То есть с [tag:мобильные-приложения] синонимизировать не надо.

Comment: @Глеб И кстати, при выпиливании метки [tag:приложения] про андроид было не больше трети вопров.

Comment: @Зонтик, ладно, сдаюсь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Раз удалили метки [по](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be), [software](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/software) и [программы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b) ([ссылка на обсуждение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7041/)), то и метки [приложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f) и [приложение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) не нужны.

Кто будет искать информацию по метке [приложение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)/[приложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)? А какую информацию несёт в себе метка? На эти вопрос ответы очевидны: никто и никакую.

Их можно удалить вручную и заменить на более подходящие. В сумме 106 вопросов. Если чистить даже по 15-20 вопросов в день, то через неделю метки будут стёрты с лица ruSO.

**Дополнение:**
Метку [приложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f) убрал со всех 24 вопросов и заменил более подходящими. [приложение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) пока **осталась**, и с ним 82 вопроса. Но и с этим справимся.

**Дополнение 2**: Метку [приложение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) тоже снял с всех вопросов.

Comment: Не стоит так сразу сжигать метки с сотней вопросов, дайте возможность заинтересованным участникам высказаться. Даже если метка явно бессмысленная, могут быть разные мнения, на что ее стоит заменять в каких случаях. На EN SO, например, существует определенный процесс сожжения меток: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/8674428

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight [на enSO аналогичные метки сожгли](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371416/yet-another-application-for-burnination). А на счёт того "на что тег заменять" - неужели мы будем здесь, на мете это обсуждать? Вопросов с меткой много и они все разные!